# Complex integral $I=\int_{|z|=2} \frac{z^3 e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z+1}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I have this integral from someone who told me it has a nice answer.$$I=\int_{|z|=2} \frac{z^3 e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z+1}dz$$ I tried to evaluate this using residues theorem, and expanded into series to find the residue at $\infty$$$f(z)=z^3[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nz^n(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n!)z^n})]$$ And with Cauchy product:$$f(z)=z^3(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k z^{2k-n}}{(n-k)!})$$ Now I am lost, how can I find the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in this double series? It seems that is not just a simple number... Or shall I use another method?

Comment: Note that since $|z|=2$, the term $\frac{1}{z+1}$ cannot be expanded as a geometric series. I think I'd try a substitution before expanding in Taylor series.

Comment: Oh.. So I wasnt even close...

Comment: You're close, it just requires a little more care.

Comment: I am thinking of letting $u=\frac{1}{z}$ in order to expand into taylor series afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $u = \frac 1z$, so the integral is over the circle $|u| = 1/2$, and is now clockwise.  $z = \frac 1u$, so $dz = -\frac{1}{u^2} du$, and so the minus signs cancel
$$\begin{align}I &= \int_{|u| = \frac{1}{2}} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^3 e^u}{\frac{1}{u} + 1} \frac{1}{u^2}\, du\\ 
&=\int_{|u| = \frac{1}{2}} \frac{e^u}{u^4(u+1)}\,du.\end{align}$$
Then we have to find the residue of $f(z) = \frac{e^u}{u^4 (u+1)}$ at $0$, which can be done using a Taylor series as standard.

$$\begin{align} \frac{e^u}{u^4 (u+1)} &= \frac{1}{u^4}\left(1+u+\frac{1}{2}u^2 + \frac{1}{6}u^3+O(u^4)\right)\left(1-u+u^2-u^3 + O(u^4)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{u^4}\left(1+u(1-1)+u^2\left(1-1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+u^3\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2}+1-1\right)+O(u^4)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{u^4}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}u^2 - \frac{1}{3}u^3 + O(u^4) \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{u^4}+\frac{1}{2u^2}-\frac{1}{3u}+O(1).\end{align}$$
So, the residue of $f(z)$ at $0$ is $-\frac{1}{3}$, and the integral is $-\frac{2\pi i}{3}$.

Comment: You should get a series which works - I'll add this to the post

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. Thanks, B. Mehta.

Answer (score 3):

For $|z|\ge2$,
$$
\frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{z+1}=\frac{z^3}{z+1}+\frac{z^2}{z+1}+\frac12\frac{z}{z+1}+\frac16\frac1{z+1}+O\!\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)
$$
Since the singularities of $\frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{z+1}$ are all inside $|z|=2$, the integrals over $|z|=R$ are the same for all $R\ge2$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{z+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\int_{|z|=2}\left(\frac{z^3}{z+1}+\frac{z^2}{z+1}+\frac12\frac{z}{z+1}+\frac16\frac1{z+1}\right)\mathrm{d}z\\
&=2\pi i\left(-1+1-\frac12+\frac16\right)\\[3pt]
&=-\frac{2\pi i}{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Zacky: The integral of the $O\!\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)$ error vanishes as $|z|\to\infty$, since the integral is $O\!\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)$.

Comment: I hope I dont annoy you, but how you know the complexity of the integral is $O\!\left(\frac1{|z|}\right)$? To be fair when I saw it first I thought $\frac{1}{z+1}$ also vanishes, while the rest are fine.

Comment: @Zacky:  Since the length of the path is $2\pi R$, $$\left|\,\int_{|z|=R}\frac1{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\,\right|\le\frac{2\pi R}{R^2}=\frac{2\pi}R$$